# Fallout 4. Will stats over than 10 work?

Tags: fallout-4

If i will boost my stats for 11 and more with items or buffs, will it work? Are there any formulas to calculate?
This question is not about "how increase" but about "what it will give for me". Is there limit to stats benefits.

**UPD.**
Those who marks this question as duplicate, please, show me answer from that topic. I do not see it there.

Comment: Here's the answer from the other topic: "Things that provide temp boosts such as perks ex. Night Person, drugs, clothing or other items will raise it above 10 as long as its equipped or in effect but since its just a temp boost you can NOT use it to get perks you normally wouldn't have access to but it does give you all the other advantages of having a higher stat an example would be for strength being able to carry more." Not the most well-crafted sentence ever, so I can understand missing it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, special over 10 give the same bonuses per point of special.

You can have 11 in every special if you have 10 and then pick up the bobblehead for that special.